# What is the opposite of REGEXP_LIKE in oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table that contains a list of categories with their respective regexs.
I want to get the category of an input depending on its regexp. EX:

I have this tab:

```
'MAIL'        '^[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$'
'TELFR-I'     '^(\+33|0033)[1-9][0-9]{8}'
'TELFR'       '^(0)[1-9][0-9]{8}'
```

When I give `abc@abc.com` I want to get 'Mail'.

Is this possible? thanks.

Comment: In any case - why the **opposite** of REGEXP_LIKE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use REGEXP_LIKE for this purpose.
Check this:

```
SELECT t1.Category FROM TABLE1 t1
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('abc@abc.com', t1.regex)
```

Comment: Already tried that. It would give this error ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using? It works fine for me.

Comment: 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0

Comment: Oh my bad. It actually works fo me too. Great thank you.